# efficiently match values and average column where TRUE

Tags: r, matching

Having trouble just matching values and taking an average of a column when those values match up efficiently in R. Essentially I have a chess table that I have pulled data out of and want to get the average for each player's pre-chess rating based on who they played against.

If I have a dataframe:

```
number <- c(1:10) #number assigned to each player
rating <- c(1000,1200,1210,980,1000,1001,1100,1300,1100,1250) #rating of the player
df <- data.frame(number= number, rating = rating)

p1_games <- c(1,2,3,4,5) # player 1 played against players 2,3,4,5
```

I want to essentially do is check to see if the values in p1_games match a number in the table, and when they match, average the values in the ratings column.
I just want to return one value and so I've had trouble trying to make ifelse() work:

```
avg_rate <- ifelse(p1_games %in% df$number, sum(df$rating)/length(p1_games)) #not working
```

I would like to like to avoid looping if possible but if there's no other efficient way that's fine. Just can't figure out what's up here. Ideally I'd like to apply this logic over many p*_games vectors.

If p1_games in df$number, sum each corresponding rating and divide by the number or ratings. So the **output for p1_games in this case would be** `1078`. I feel like this is really simple but can't quite make this work.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when making an example with random data. And, even though you cannot write working code for your desired output, it would be best to show what your desired output is for your example. (That may mean reducing the size of your example down to where you can compute the result by hand.)

Comment: In addition to what Frank said, what exactly is your intended output for the two example `p*_games` vectors?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I've made edits to hopefully really simplify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%in%` is great at this kind of thing

```
> mean(df[number %in% p1_games, "rating"])
[1] 1078
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate answer using `data.table`, which may be of use with larger data sets (although since `p1_games` isn't a column, I'm not sure):

```
> setDT(df)
> df[number %in% p1_games, mean(rating)]
[1] 1078
```